# How to find a branch of $\mathrm{log}(iz)$ such that it's analytic in a fixed region

Tags: complex-analysis

The question as a whole is given as (I'll remove part a since it's not relevant I think)

> Define $f$ and $g$ by $f(z) = \mathrm{Log}(iz)$ and $g(z) = z^{-1}\mathrm{Log}(z+1)$.
>   b. Find a branch of $\mathrm{log}(iz)$ which is analytic in the region $\{z:{\bf Im}(z)>0\}.$
>   where $\mathrm{log}$ is multi-valued.

I know how to first find the set of points in the plane so that the Log of some polynomial allows it to be analytic, by using the principal branch $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$. But I'm not sure how I could do the reverse.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555020/branch-cut-for-log-iz-in-the-region-z-mathrmimz0

Comment: Removing any ray through the origin and infinity as long as it's not above the real axis should probably work

Comment: If $U$ is a simply connected open set not containing $0$ then $\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic on $U$ and so is $L(z) = \int_a^z \frac{1}{s}ds$

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is the principle branch of logarithm then $g(-iz)+i\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is such a branch.